# IOS：Unable to get the iphone 4s and ipad 3 imei

Tags: ios, imei

For iphone mobile imei's code program I found online, on the iphone 3gs/4/ipad 1/2 generations can access, but, in the majority of iphone4s and ipad3 but not normal access to, and do not knowWhat are the procedures to get to it

Answer (score 2):

The App Store is rejecting apps that access the IMEI now. You shouldn't need it.

Comment: My application is not on the app store, just learning to use

Comment: I guess my answer would have to be "don't worry about it," then. I'm sure there's a hacky way, but it wouldn't be usable an app you could ship.